# How can write two statement within then statement?

Tags: if-statement, haskell, tuples

I am writing a code in Haskell which take a list of 0's and 1's like [1,1,0,0,1,0,1] return a Pair(tuple) of the number occurrence of 0 and 1 in a list like (3,4).

Here is my code:

```
inc :: Int -> Int
inc x = (\x -> x + 1) x

count :: [Int] -> (Int,Int)
c = (0,0)
count x = 
        if null x
            then c
        else if head x == 0
            then do
                inc (fst c)
                count (tail x)
        else if head x == 1
            then do
                inc (snd c) 
                count (tail x)
```

I have also tried doing it in a guarded form:

```
count :: [Int] -> (Int,Int)
c = (0,0)
count x 
          | null x =  c
          | head x == 0 = inc (fst c) >> count (tail x)
          | head x == 1 = inc (snd c) >> count (tail x)
```

The main problem is that I am not sure how to implement two function in one then statement.

Comment: Too much manual work. Try something more like `counts xs = (length $ filter (==0) xs, length $ filter (==1) xs)`. Sorry, I know I'm not really answering your question.

Comment: `inc (fst c)` does nothing when sequenced, since it doesn't carry out side effects. Remeber, in Haskell, nearly everything is immutable. You can't modify `c`. Use a fold if you insist of doing this manually, or take @zorans suggestion, since it's probably the simplest way to achieve this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're thinking all imperatively. Something like `do { inc (fst c); count (tail x) }` would only make sense if `c` was some kind of mutable state variable. Haskell variables are not mutable, so `inc` can't *modify* the `fst` of `c`, it can only give you *a modified copy*. This might become clearer if you rewrite `inc` to the completely equivalent simpler form:

```
inc x = x + 1
```

(In fact, `inc = (+1)` would also do.)

Now, in `count`, you're trying to carry on and increment a single accumulator variable through the recursion loop. You can do that, but you need to be explicit about passing the *modified* version to the recursive call:

```
count = go (0,0)
 where go :: (Int,Int) -> [Int] -> (Int,Int)
       go c x
        | null x       = c
        | head x == 0  = go (first inc c) (tail x)
        | head x == 1  = go (second inc c) (tail x)
```

This pattern of defining a small local helper function (`go` is just an arbitrary name, I could have also called it `getTheCountingDone`) and using it as the [“loop body” of the recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) is quite common in Haskell. Basically `go (0,0)` “initialises” `c` to the value `(0,0)`, then starts the first loop iteration. For the second iteration, you recurse to e.g. `go (first inc c)`, i.e. you start the loop again with the updated `c` variable.

I've used [`first` and `second`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Arrow.html#v:first) for incrementing the respective tuple field. `fst` only *reads* the first field, i.e. gives you its value, whereas `first` makes a tuple-update function from an element-update function. Instead of `import Control.Arrow` you could also define this yourself:

```
first :: (a->b) -> (a,y) -> (b,y)
first f (a, y) = (f a, y)
second :: (a->b) -> (x,a) -> (x,b)
second f (x, a) = (x, f a)
```

(The `Control.Arrow` version is actually more general, but you don't need to worry about that – you can use it in just the same way.)

Note that deconstructing lists with `head` and `tail` is heavily eschewed in Haskell: it's easy to get wrong – you may forget to check the list is nonempty before accessing an element, which will throw a nasty runtime error. Better use *pattern matching*:

```
count = go (0,0)
 where go c []      = c
       go c (0:xs)  = go (first inc c) xs
       go c (1:xs)  = go (second inc c) xs
```

Actually this is still not safe: you don't have exhaustive cases; the function fails if the list contains anything but zeroes or ones. Perhaps you'd like to count all zero and *nonzero* elements?

```
count = go (0,0)
 where go c []      = c
       go c (0:xs)  = go (first inc c) xs
       go c (_:xs)  = go (second inc c) xs
```

Comment: I would curry the `c` argument into two arguments, making `first` unneeded.

Comment: @USERSFU: I've added some explanation.

Comment: Unfortunately for the `Bifunctor` laws, `first` and `second` are actually lazier than your definitions suggest. This is because they're used to tie weird `Arrow`y knots. But it means that they have nasty potential performance gotchas in other situations. As a result, I virtually never use them.

Comment: @dfeuer: that's good to know and a pity. Do you have a reference for why this is necessary and how it affects performance?

Comment: @leftaroundabout, I don't. I think Edward Kmett told me it's necessary to support the `ArrowLoop` stuff. I suspect `Data.Bifunctor` followed the semantics of `Control.Arrow` to avoid confusion. As for performance, lazy pairs can definitely lead to space leaks, and if strictness analysis doesn't erase them will lead to thunk creation. It should generally work to use `first f $! p`. You just have to remember it all the time.

Answer (score 1):

another alternative

```
> import Data.List(group,sort)
> count = tuplify . map length . group . sort
       where tuplify [x,y] = (x,y)
```

Comment: `both length . partition (== 0)`, where `both f (a,b) = (f a, f b)` would have O(n), compared to the O(n log n) sort.

Comment: I don't like the unnecessary partial function.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to filter the list twice, once keeping the zeroes, and once keeping the ones:

```
count :: [Int] -> (Int, Int)
count nums = (length (filter (0 ==) nums), length (filter (1 ==) nums))
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to have a second parameter for your `count` function which keeps track of what you have already counted:

```
count :: [Int] -> (Int, Int) -> (Int, Int)

-- if the list is empty, return the ones and zeroes already counted
count [] (zeroes, ones) = (zeroes, ones)

-- if first element is a 0, increment the existing count for zeroes
-- and count the rest
count (0:more) (zeroes, ones) = count more (zeroes + 1, ones)

-- as before, but the first element is a 1
count (1:more) (zeroes, ones) = count more (zeroes, ones + 1)
```

When we call count, we have to give it a 'starting count' of `(0,0)`:

```
count [1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1] (0,0)
```

which returns `(3,5)` as the first 0 in the initial pair is incremented 3 times by the zeroes in the list, and the second 0 in the initial pair is incremented 5 times by the ones in the list.

This solution is a common functional programming style called 'accumulating parameter'.